# can I get data out of database within a php include?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, include

I wonder if I could get datas out of sql database within a php include..?

Now I got:

```
<?php include ("../foldername-Mark/file.php"); ?>
```

I would like to get for example the foldername out of database...
Why:
I got hundreds of folders, so to include a certain `file.php` within the main frame
I would have to realy write each foldername rather then getting the foldername out of the id of the customer.

something like:

```
<div id="header"> <?php include ("header.php"); ?> </div>

<div id="individual-content"> 
<?php include ("customers/name-of-customer/contend.php"); ?> </div>

<div id="footer"> <?php include ("footer.php"); ?> </div>
```

I would like to draw the name of the costumer out of database via id...
... 
in the header section of the page I have:

```
$query_Recordset7 = "SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE apartments_london.id=96";

<?php include ("../  **<?php echo $row_Recordset7['Foldername']; ?>**   /file.php"); ?>
```

I know that doesn't work, but I could not find how I could do a job like that ...
Anybody know if thats possible...?
Martin

Comment: you can pass it like `<?php include ("../" . $row_Recordset7['Foldername'] . "/file.php");>`

Comment: Great thank very much...!
Works with one little problem:
Capital letter at the beginning...
<?php include ("../" . $row_Recordset7['Foldername'] . "/file.php");>
that gives out: ../Foldername/file.php
In my database the foldernames are all with small letters - so... foldername...
therefore... php error message...

Comment: `<?php include ("../" . strtolower($row_Recordset7['Foldername']) . "/file.php");>`  will solve it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!
GREAT HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Of cource you can, if you already know folder name.
Something like this should work

```
// Retrieve row from database into $row_Record7 before building path
$path = "../{$row_Record7[Foldername]}/file.php";
include($path);
```

Comment: He is retrieving the path out of the DB

Comment: if you want to access an array key inside double quotes, it's best not to quote the key, and use curly brackets to disambiguate the expression: `$path = "/foo/{$bar[key]}/foobar.php";`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Didn't knew it, but my version still works as expected, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try making the file name before the `include` and then use the `include`:

```
$filename = '../' . $row_Recordset7['Foldername'] . '/file.php';
include $filename;
```

Comment: @cujomalainey: they're not required, `include` is a language construct, like `echo`

Comment: Right, my bad, been to long since i wrote php

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't echo the variable as that is displayed after the execute, you would store the path in a variable then do the require withe the variable as the parameter.